# How "expensive" is @Published (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, firebase, observable

I am using `ObservableObject` and `@Published` protocol and property wrapper, respectively, to asynchronously update my view structs with fetched data (in this case images). This is working fine, though I'm wondering if there might be a less "expensive" way. The image I'm fetching (profile picture) is essentially static except for the asynchronous fetching process. I'm not sure how expensive (for memory or runtime) `@Published` is, but I sense that there might be a more efficient solution. Is there?

Code:

```
class ImageFetcher: ObservableObject {
    var firebaseManager: FirebaseManager
    @Published var image: UIImage? = nil

    init(_ firebaseManager: FirebaseManager) {
        self.firebaseManager = firebaseManager
    }

    func fetchImage(id: String) {
        let ref = getRefURL(uid: id)
        print(ref)
        ref.getData(maxSize: 2051240) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        
        }
    }

    func getRefURL(uid: String) -> StorageReference {
        return firebaseManager.STORAGE.reference().child(uid)
    }
}


struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetcher: ImageFetcher

    init(_ firebaseManager: FirebaseManager) {
        self.fetcher = ImageFetcher(firebaseManager)
    }


    var body: some View {

        Button {
            fetcher.fetchImage(id: "QDhKhNe5VnWDCORoQScIVVzcpzv2")
        } label: {
            Text("Load Image")
        }

        if fetcher.image == nil {
            Text("Loading...")
        } else {
            Image(uiImage: fetcher.image!)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The code includes objects defined elsewhere in my code as well as references to my storage (which you won't be able to access) so the code is intended to be read, but not necessarily run, as it won't work.

Comment: Are you running into slowdowns or something? If not, don’t worry about it. If yes, the problem is probably somewhere else. Stuff like @Published shouldn’t have much of an effect on performance.

Comment: I'm not currently running into performance issues, though I'm worried that I might as I add views with more images and image fetchers

Comment: Try it out and profile it. Only way to know for sure.

Comment: How do you "profile" it?

Answer (score 1):

So the performance of @Published isn't that bad. SwiftUI is built to be able to handle multiple reloads of the view (which happens when an value is set to a @Published). So if you want to keep this architecture i would suggest removing the @Published and then use `objectWillChange.send()` to control when your view will update. @Published is kind of made for combine, and it doesn't seem like you are using it.

Personally i don't use classes / ObservableObject at all.

Comment: What advantage does `objectWillChange.send()` have over the `@Published` property wrapper. It seems like the *point* of `@Published` is to trigger `objectWillChange.send()` on `didSet`.

Comment: It is, but the point of `@Published` is also to open up the value for combine functions. And as you said, `@Published` trigger a reload of a view in it's didSet.. imagine you come to a view and want to populate username and password in textFields.. that means first username and then password. it's 2 reloads. if you dont have `@Published` and call objectWillChange.send() instead. it's only reloaded once.

Comment: View reloads in SwiftUI should be cheap. I think I get what you’re saying in theory, but it seems unusual to have some other mechanism than @Published to listen to updates to those fields to determine when to call objectWillSend — seems like that would have to involve some overhead as well. I’d be curious to see an example (but, I’m sure the comments here aren’t necessarily the right place)

Comment: I get what you are saying, and as i wrote in my answer. I don't even use ObservableObject, hence no @Published or objectWillChange.send() either in my project. i'm free from that :)

Comment: I’ve never seen SwiftUI used like that. Must be an interesting design pattern.